# List comprehension using if else with assignment operator

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, list-comprehension

I have a doubt in List comprehensions.
Now I have a task to use list comprehensions for sure. How we can do it using list comprehensions.

```
n=int(input("Enter the total no of plots:"))
p=0
sum1=0
sum2=0
sum3=0
a=[]
if n>0 and n<=20:
    print("Enter the numbers of each plot:")
    for i in range(n):
        b=int(input())
        if b>0:
            a.append(b)
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
            p=1
            break

else:
    p=1
    print("Invalid Input")
if p==0:
    c=[sum1=sum1+i if i%2==0 else sum2=sum2+i for i in range(n)]
    sum3=(sum1+sum2)/2
    print("The password for the file is: {:.2f}".format(sum3))
```

Comment: What are you expecting the list assign to c to look like. this doesnt look like it should be a list comprehension but instead should be a normal for loop

Comment: n=int(input("Enter the total no of plots:"))
p=0
sum1=0
sum2=0
sum3=0
a=[]
if n>0 and n<=20:
    print("Enter the numbers of each plot:")
    for i in range(n):
        b=int(input())
        if b>0:
            a.append(b)
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
            p=1
            break
        
else:
    p=1
    print("Invalid Input")
if p==0:
    c=[sum1=sum1+i if i%2==0 else sum2=sum2+i for i in range(n)]
    sum3=(sum1+sum2)/2
    print("The password for the file is: {:.2f}".format(sum3))
    
This is the entire code.

Comment: Can you edit the question with this as there is no way i can know the indentation of each code block from this. Also let me know what you expect c to contain after the list comprehension

Comment: i updated the entire code. please check once

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign variables in a list. What you are trying to do is not possible in list comprehension.

```py
c = []
sum1 = # initial value for sum1
sum2 = # initial value for sum2

for i in range(n):
  if i % 2 == 0:
    sum1 += i
    c.append(sum1)
  else:
    sum2 += i
    c.append(sum2)
```

Comment: i got it but i got a task that in the code i need to use list comprehension for sure. So is there any other approach

Answer (score 0):

Assignment is not possible in a list comprehension. Instead you can break the code into two lines of list comprehension to do what you need.

```
sum1=sum([i for i in range(n) if i%2==0])
sum2=sum([i for i in range(n) if i%2!=0])
```

Comment: i got it but i got a task that in the code i need to use list comprehension for sure. So is there any other approach

Comment: Could you please explain what is the use of variable "a". because you are appending values to it and never use it. And what do expect to be available in C